# ASP.Net module to block DOS attacks

Tags: asp.net, security, c#-4.0, denial-of-service

I would like to programmatically protect my ASP.Net 4.0 website from harmful repeated requests. If I notice high request number from an IP then I would like to block that IP for a certain time (ex. in case someone writes a FOR cycle and requests the webpage over and over). I know that the best defense is not to server data to unauthenticated users but unfortunately some public pages are data-heavy and there is nothing I can do about it.

I looked at some solutions today but none of them satisfied me. I am guessing that this is a very common issue and I would not like to implement something like this from scratch.

I saw a [solution implemented as a module](http://madskristensen.net/post/Block-DoS-attacks-easily-in-ASPNET.aspx) and I would like to do the same but better. I need the following features:

- Block IP after detecting a non-human pattern
- Preferably implemented as an HttpModule
- Allow the crawlers through
- Block should expire after a certain interval
- Lightweight: the module should not slow down the website or access the database

Comment: So you know what you won, why not made it and post it here ? The crawlers is something that easy fix, but easy simulate by a hacker, the expire needs a timer, the non-human pattern have to do with post backs, and the HttpModule is just simple code...

Comment: Also for me, the DOS attack must be separate code from Non-human pattern check. The one is attack to crash you down, the other is attack to make many actions to full your pages your spam data, or get the control. You need different tolerance for login page, than contact page, than enter comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 approaches for the above problem:

1. Using IIS Dynamic IP Restrictions module
2. Using HackerSpray Library on Github

For 1st approach,

> The Dynamic IP Restrictions Extension for IIS provides IT Professionals and Hosters a configurable module that helps mitigate or block Denial of Service Attacks or cracking of passwords through Brute-force by temporarily blocking Internet Protocol (IP) addresses of HTTP clients who follow a pattern that could be conducive to one of such attacks. This module can be configured such that the analysis and blocking could be done at the Web Server or the Web Site level.

---

**source**: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions:

For 2nd Approach,

> HackerSpray uses Redis to maintain high-performance counters for actions and origin IPs. You call Hacker.Defend(key, ip) to check if a certain key or IP has made too many hits. You can maintain blacklists for key, IP or IP Range. HackerSpray checks against too many hits on a key, too many hits on an IP, or IP falling within blacklists. It also allows blacklisting a certain key for a certain IP or blocking a certain key for all IPs on-the-fly. Handy when you want to block a user out of certain URLs.

It comes with a HttpModule, which protects your entire website.

Example calls:

```
var result = await Hacker.DefendAsync("/Account/LogOn", Request.UserHostAddress);

if (result == Hacker.Result.TooManyHitsFromOrigin) 
    await Hacker.BlacklistOriginAsync(Request.UserHostAddress, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)); 

else if (result == Hacker.Result.TooManyHitsOnKey) 
    await Hacker.BlacklistKeyAsync("/Account/LogOn", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));


 Hacker.DefendAsync("/Account/PasswordReset", Request.UserHostAddress, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 100);
 Hacker.DefendAsync("Username" + username, Request.UserHostAddress);
 Hacker.DefendAsync("Comment", Request.UserHostAddress);
```

LoginController Example:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
   return await Hacker.DefendAsync<ActionResult>(async (success, fail) =>
   {
       // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
       // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to       shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return await success(RedirectToLocal(returnUrl));
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return await fail(View("Lockout"));
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return await success(RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe }));
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return await fail(View(model));
    }
},
blocked => new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden),
    "ValidLogin:" + model.Email, 3, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    "InvalidLogin:" + model.Email, 4, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    Request.GetClientIp()
); }
```

In the web.config, you need to specify which paths to protect using the HttpModule.

```
<HackerSprayConfig redis="localhost" prefix="AuthTest:">
<keys>
  <add name="/Account/LogOn/" post="true" maxAttempts="100" interval="00:10:00" mode="perkeyperorigin" />
  <add name="/Home/" post="false" maxAttempts="10000" interval="00:01:00" mode="perorigin" />
  <add name="/" post="false" maxAttempts="10000" interval="00:01:00" mode="perorigin" />
</keys> </HackerSprayConfig>
```

- redis - This is the connection string to Redis server.
- prefix - All keys created in redis is prefixed with this.
- keys - one entry per path that you want to protect
- name - The Path to match
- post - true = POST, false = GET
- maxAttempts - max number of hits to allow
- interval - hits for how long?
- mode - How to count the hits and apply blocking

  - perkey - count hits from all IPs to this key. For ex, allow maximum 1000000 hits to Home page in 10 minutes period.
  - perorigin - While checking hits to this key, if the origin IP has produced more than the maxAttempts hit overall on any key, then block. For ex, allow 1000 hits per IP, to any key, but do this check on Login page hit.
  - perkeyorigin - Count hits to this key, per IP. For example, 1000 hits per IP on the Login page.

---

**Credits / Source**: https://github.com/oazabir/HackerSpray